# Custom NSDatePicker graphical calender-like pickers

Tags: cocoa

For example, I wanted to have a popover or something that would let me choose from a table (say, like the periodic table, IPA chart, etc.…) in a similar style as a graphical NSDatePicker. In addition, how could I make it select multiple cells at once?

Is there already a default Cocoa way to do so? If not, from what class could such a thing be done and maybe some pointers on from where to proceed?

(I apologize if this is another common question, but I couldn't find it on my own.)

Answer (score 0):

It is very surprising, but on a lot of points, I think that OSX's GUI is very limited unlike iOS.

So, I'm afraid that you have to create your own component from scratch.

Or you can have a look at these open-source controls written for OSX :

For choosing a date : You can use MLCalendarView (Calendar-OSX) available on [Github](https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/Calendar-OSX).

For displaying a TableView, with multiple selections (very similar to UITableView) : you can use this great open-source component : PXListView available on [Github](https://github.com/Perspx/PXListView).